# changing spynner User Agent doesnt work

Tags: javascript, python, user-agent, spynner

We're having the following situation:
We need to access a site which need to be accessed only with MSIE.

For this reason, we must change the spynner User Agent, because this is not MSIE by default.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import spynner
from pyquery import PyQuery
import time
import sys
tipo_navegador = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))"

br = spynner.Browser(
            ignore_ssl_errors=True,
            user_agent=tipo_navegador,
            debug_level=spynner.WARNING,
            debug_stream=sys.stderr)
br.create_webview()
br.show()
br.set_html_parser(PyQuery)
br.load("https://myurl.com/index.php")
br.browse()
br.close()
```

Debugging Spynner we saw the modified User Agent:

```
Page load started
Request: GET https://myurl.com/index.php
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))
```

From Web site we receive the default User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite `navigator.userAgent` value you can use
[this gist](https://gist.github.com/moehlone/bed7dd6cb38fc55bd640).
Test it running the following script:

```
browser = spynner.Browser(user_agent='myFakeUserAgent',
                          headers=headers_list)

browser.runjs(change_user_agent_script + 'document.write((navigator.userAgent))')
browser.browse()
```

Where `change_user_agent_script` is a string containing this gist.